# Resolve conflicts on git merge octopus

Tags: git

Octopus merge means to merge more than 2 heads.

How should the user compare files using ordinary 3-way merge tools?

3 files are passed to the merge tool: BASE, LOCAL, REMOTE

How many and what combinations are required for 3 heads?

Answer (score 8):

You should not use an octopus merge in this situation. Octopus merges should only be used in cases where there are no merge conflicts or the conflicts are so simple that you can resolve them manually without merge tools.

In your situation you should just do 2 normal merges, which will have exactly the same effect as an octopus merge, but will allow your to use your merging tools.

You could just check out the different branch-heads’ versions manually and run your 3-way merge tool twice to get your octopus merge working. But that would be exactly  the same process as doing two normal merges – just more complicated.

If you want to do an octopus merge, so that your history looks nicer, just do two merges and rewrite your history afterwards.

Comment: +1, but octopus can still shows conflicts, right? Just not when more than 2 files have conflict (http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/10/git-tip-of-week-merging-revisited.html).

Comment: Good question. I was curious so I tested it. And it only works in some very specific cases (like the one on your link). If you have three branches of your master head, two with conflicting changes and the third one with non-conflicting changes, git will fail the merge and not offer any conflict resolution.

Comment: How do you rewrite your history afterwards?

Comment: @drumfire that is a little bit involved. If google doesn’t help, you should create a separate question on SO. But I would also strongly recommend not do any rewriting here, as you will loose the information about your conflict resolution.

Comment: Is there any way to force conflict resolution with an octopus merge? In my scenario the branches are co-dependent so merging one-by-one will result in broken commits which I prefer to avoid. It would be nice if I could merge and resolve all conflicts in one commit so that every commit passes tests.

Comment: @drumfire once you have done the two merges, [here's one way to rewrite the branch afterwards](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75088041/184546).