# Squashing Two Merge Commits Into a Single Merge Commit?

Tags: git, merge

I have the following scenario:

```
* a278b6b (HEAD -> feature1) Change i to j
| * c9550d0 (feature3) Print only odds
|/
| * befb5e9 (feature2) 2*z in baz loop
|/
* aa36658 Print only evens
```

Now, what I would like to do is merge the `feature1`, `feature2`, and `feature3` branches together into a new branch, so that this new commit contains all information from the 3 branches. Normally you could just do an octopus merge and get exactly what I'm looking for, but in this case, there are merge conflicts between the three branches that need to be resolved manually. So, after merging the branches one at a time in order to resolve all merge conflicts, I'm left with:

```
*   6679d6c (HEAD -> DI) merge feature3
|\
| * c9550d0 (feature3) Print only odds
* |   5b03abb merge feature2
|\ \
| * | befb5e9 (feature2) 2*z in baz loop
| |/
* / a278b6b (feature1) Change i to j
|/
* aa36658 Print only evens
```

where `DI` is the branch that all three `feature` branches will be merged into.

The problem is that now I have two merge commits here: `5b03abb` and `6679d6c`. I'd like for there to only be a single merge commit (for cleanliness & maintenance), but the merge conflicts mean that I can't just do a straight octopus merge. Is there a way to somehow squash the two merge commits into the same commit like you would do for standard commits, or some other merge strategy that I should be using in order to get a single merge commit with 3 parents?

Comment: Nor do I believe that the octopus merge is what you really want, but that's another story.

Comment: "after merging the branches one at a time" Ah. There's the problem.

Comment: @matt the octopus merge strat will reject any merge requiring conflict resolution, so the merge conflicts in this situation mean the OP can't just do a straight octopus merge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a commit from thin air using the original branches as parents and the final tree (files, contents) that you have as.... *the tree*:

```
git commit-tree -p a278b6b -p c9550d0 -p befb5e9 -m "some merge" 6679d6c^{tree}
```

That will print a commit ID. Set the branch you want there, say, main:

```
git branch -f main the-id-from-previous-command
```

Comment: I've never seen `<hash>^{tree}` before -- what should I be searching for to learn more about it?

Comment: @Pacopenguin: this syntax  is documented in gitrevisions(5), which is online at https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions

Comment: @Pacopenguin [A more specific link](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrevgtlttypegtemegemv0998commitem)

Comment: I've tried your suggestion and it works ! But, would it be possible to elaborate a bit more on why the merge commits are actually removed when you do this ? Is it because after forcefully reassigning branch `6679d6c`, the merge commit branches become dangling references (i.e. there aren't any branches referring to them, and they aren't a parent of any other commit)?

Comment: @Pacopenguin the merge commits aren't actually "removed". The `commit-tree` command is basically saying: make a commit, set it's parents to be these 3 commits, set the message to be "some merge", and set the *state* of the commit to be identical to the *state* of commit 6679d6c. (That's the commit you ended up with after both merges.) Note you could theoretically use `commit-tree` to make any commit look like whatever you want, and bypassing merges altogether.

Comment: @TTT Yeah, I didn't alter my previous comment in time, but I can still see the merge commits in `.git/objects` so they weren't literally removed, but they are both no longer present in the output of `git log`, and I was trying to ask about why that is.

Comment: `git log` starts from whatever starting points you give it, you can add `--reflog` to also look through your `HEAD` history for any other commits you might have had checked out.

Comment: Sometimes you just need to pull out the big guns.... the low-level commands that are not for the faint of heart. Thanks for helping out with the explanations while I was gone.